# In Rust, why is not `extern "system"` compatible with `extern "C"` on macOS?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to wrap a C library that makes use of callbacks and they need different calling conventions depending on OS.

On Windows they need to be `stdcall` (or `C` if x64). On Linux and macOS they need to be `C`.

I use bindgen to generate the bindings, but I also want to wrap that layer in another layer hiding the callbacks. I thought the following should work:

```
extern "system" .........
```

but I get these kind of errors (currently on macOS):

```
E0308: mismatched types
  label: expected "C" fn, found "system" fn
  note: expected type `extern "C" fn(*mut ...
```

I would like to share the wrapper layer for all platforms. Do I need to duplicate the wrapper layer or use macros for this? Should `extern "system"` work? Is this a bug?

Edit:

I ended up writing a workaround: https://crates.io/crates/extern_attrib

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would have assumed that  there's no special logic here; a functions ABI only matches if it matches exactly.

Comment: I did expect "system" to get replaced by the appropriate ABI name for the target platform, but Rust FFI is all new to me so I expect my expectations to be wrong most of the time. I implemented a macro as a workaround, I'll post it here later. Thanks for the edit of my question btw :)